# ALL or null with enums?

Tags: c#, enums, null

I've noticed I've been doing this inconsistently within the same project.  In some places, I'll have an enum with an ALL option, and in others I'll have my enum as a nullable type with a null value indicating all (or no filter.)

I noticed it when I had to write something like `if (Region != null && Region != Regions.ALL)`.

Is there a reason to go one way or the other?

Comment: Enum names should be UpperCamelCase

Comment: I feel like it's an object-relational impedance mismatch issue.  In the application side, it makes sense to have options like "All", "All West Coast Regions", and "All East Coast Regions".

However, I'm often using the enum casted to int directly as a SqlParameter.  In these methods, I would need to check for each of these instances and convert them to proper SQL.  (Instead of "and region = 1" I would need "and region in (2, 4, 5)").  Unfortunately,  SqlParameters don't work well with lists either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where Enums that you need to specify either an "All" or "Null" type, I usually go with the `Flag` attribute and use bitwise `&` and `|`.  That is a much more flexible solution.

As for making a nullable type or having one option be "All", I think if it makes sense to you, then I see no problem with it.  I just prefer using Flags.

Comment: An `All` member is useful for `[Flags]` enums also... there's no rule that all flags must be mutually exclusive.

Comment: @BenVoigt - totally.  When I have these kinds of frequent combinations, I'll do an `All = 0x111` or whatever.  You can also do something like `PizzaAndBreadsticks = 0x101` if that is a frequent combo that you want an explicit definition for.

Answer (score 7):

Using `Regions.All` is more explicit as far as conveying the meaning goes. You can "assign" that meaning to `null`, and the computer would be fine with it. The *readers* of your program, however, would need to decypher that meaning from the way you use the `null` enum value, or from reading your comments. `Regions.All`, on the other hand, is self-documenting and self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, we use `null` to mean 'unspecified' or 'non-existent' or 'non-applicable'. So, in the case of a filter, it makes sense to allow for null, because it means 'no filtering'.

In addition, an enum called `Regions` probably has values like `Northeast`, `Southeast`, `Midwest`, `Southwest`, and `West`. Now, please correct me if I am wrong, but I do not think there is any region called "All" in the USA. During my several year long stay over there I heard the weatherman on the TV speaking of the weather in the West, and of the weather in the Southeast, etc. but never of the weather in some place called "All". So, I am inclined to believe that there is no such region. Therefore, including "All" in an enum of regions is a hack. Suddenly, the `Regions` enum is not about regions; instead it is about regions and/or filtering thereof. Shifts in meaning of this kind are something to be aware of in programming and to generally avoid.

Comment: I disagree with ever assigning null to an enum variable.  It takes nothing to create a value of `None` or `All` that perfectly describes what `null` actually means in this context.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food Yes, of course it takes nothing. And then you have a list of 'regional manager' objects every one of which has a 'region' field, and it is perfectly valid to have a regional manager who manages a region called 'None' or a region called 'Any'. Congratulations, you have just raped a fundamental data integrity principle.

Comment: I see your point now that adding indescrete members to what should be a discrete enumeration is inconsistant.  Something doesn't sit right with me using `null`, but it's got me thinking.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food Well, some alternatives that I can think of would be: 1) another `enum` called `RegionsToSearchFor` which mirrors `Regions` and adds `Any` at the end, or 2) a `struct` containing a `Region` and a flag indicating whether to filter by this region or ignore it. You thought null was bad? Try one of these!  Perhaps now the null approach does not sound that bad after all.